# Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560030580.)"

Tags: avplayer, avaudiosession

I was using  AVPlayer to play online mp3  stream ! When I pause the player

```
[AVPlayer pause];
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
session.delegate = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
[session setActive:NO error:&error];
NSLog([error description]);
```

I met the error ,  Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560030580.)"

Can anyone tell me why and how to resolve it?

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?

Comment: When some background app was playing music ，AVPlayer would interrupt that background music and begin play ! When AVplayer has finished,the background music can't continue playing!

Answer (score 10):

I encounter this problem too. I googled and see this post more than one time. From [the forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/38917), someone said, the error code can be figured out by `AVAudioSession.h`.

In my case, the problem seems to be `race condition` problem. It never happens on my `iPhone 5s`, but happens on other devices generally, ex: `iPhone6 Plus`.

As far as I know, the error code `560030580` means `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeIsBusy`.

---

From `AVAudioSession.h`, the following is defined.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, AVAudioSessionErrorCode)
{
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeNone                         =  0,
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeMediaServicesFailed          = 'msrv',           /* 0x6D737276, 1836282486   */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeIsBusy                       = '!act',           /* 0x21616374, 560030580    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeIncompatibleCategory         = '!cat',           /* 0x21636174, 560161140    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotInterruptOthers        = '!int',           /* 0x21696E74, 560557684    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeMissingEntitlement           = 'ent?',           /* 0x656E743F, 1701737535   */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeSiriIsRecording              = 'siri',           /* 0x73697269, 1936290409   */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartPlaying           = '!pla',           /* 0x21706C61, 561015905    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeCannotStartRecording         = '!rec',           /* 0x21726563, 561145187    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeBadParam                     = -50,
    AVAudioSessionErrorInsufficientPriority             = '!pri',           /* 0x21707269, 561017449    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeResourceNotAvailable         = '!res',           /* 0x21726573, 561145203    */
    AVAudioSessionErrorCodeUnspecified                  = 'what'            /* 0x77686174, 2003329396   */
} NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/1616597-setactive :

> Deactivating an audio session that has running audio objects stops
> them, deactivates the session, and returns an
> AVAudioSessionErrorCodeIsBusy error.

As far as I understand it means that your audio is still playing and you try to deactivate the session - it will be deactivated but you will be noted this way about that fact.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the answer: Disconnect from Airplay.

Comment: What if I wanna use my Airpods?? My app requires headphones so this is not a solution imo

Comment: Yes, there should be a better solution