# Stopping a `CallbackInstrument` prior to setting `AVAudioSession.setActive(false)`

Tags: swift, avfoundation, audiokit

In attempt to pause my signal chain when a user puts the app into the background, or is interrupted by a phone call, I am trying to handle the interruption by stopping all playing nodes and setting the `AVAudioSession().setActive(false)` as per convention.

It seems fine to call `stop()` on all nodes *except* `CallbackInstrument`, which crashes at line 231 of *DSPBase.cpp* in *CAudioKitEX from the `AudioKitEX` repo :

```
void DSPBase::processOrBypass(AUAudioFrameCount frameCount, AUAudioFrameCount bufferOffset) {

    if (isStarted) {
        process(FrameRange{bufferOffset, frameCount});
    } else {

        // Advance all ramps.
        stepRampsBy(frameCount);

        // Copy input to output.
        if (inputBufferLists.size() and !bCanProcessInPlace) {
            for (int channel=0; channel< channelCount; ++channel) {
                auto input = (const float *)inputBufferLists[0]->mBuffers[channel].mData + bufferOffset;
                auto output = (float *)outputBufferList->mBuffers[channel].mData + bufferOffset;
                std::copy(input, input+frameCount, output);
            }
        }

        // Generators should be silent.
        if (inputBufferLists.empty()) {
            zeroOutput(frameCount, bufferOffset);
        }
    }

}
```

My `CallbackInstrument` is attached to a `Sequencer` as a discrete track. The crash occurs when the sequencer is playing and the app goes into the background, which I then call a method to stop all current sequencers, stop all active nodes prior to calling `AVAudioSession.setSession(false)`.

I would simply ignore this and/or not stop `CallbackInstrument` however, by not attempting to stop or reset the `CallbackInstrument` node, `AVAudioSession` catches an error:

```
AVAudioSession_iOS.mm:1271  Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.
Error seting audio session false:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "(null)"
```

Error code=560030580 refers to `AVAudioSessionErrorCodeIsBusy` as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439767/error-domain-nsosstatuserrordomain-code-560030580-the-operation-couldn-t-be-com)

**Question:**

If stopping a `Sequencer` with a `CallbackInstrument` does *not* in fact stop rendering audio/midi from the callback, how do we safely stop a signal chain with a `CallbackInstrument` in order to prepare for `AVAudioSession.setActive(false)`?

I have an example repo of the issue which can be found [here](https://github.com/maksutovic/AudioKitTroubleshooting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nicely presented question by the way :)

Seems like doing it this way does not guarantee that the `audioBufferList` in process or bypass is populated, while it does report that the size() == 1, its pointer to `audioBuferList[0]` is `nill`...

Possibly there should be an additional check for this?

However, if instead of calling `stop()` on every node in your `AudioManager.sleep()` if you call `engine.stop()`

and conversely `self.start()` in your `AudioManager.wake()` instead of start on all your nodes... This avoids your error and should stop/start all nodes in the process.

Comment: Great I will give it a shot, though usually in AudioKit5 we usually want to avoid starting/stopping the engine often, but perhaps a peculiar behavior with CallbackInstrument

Comment: Possibly a better solution then would be to call engine.pause() rather than engine.stop() 

Seems like this would be the more appropriate call as not to release resources unnecessarily.